# Overriding multiple config values in Typesafe config when using an uberjar to deploy

Tags: scala, deployment, sbt, akka, typesafe-config

I've an Akka application which uses multiple configuration values (IP address, port numbers) defined in `resource/application.conf`. I'm using the `sbt-assembly` plugin to create an uber jar and then deploying this jar.

Is there a way to override  the whole `application.conf` file by using another file that is outside the uber jar ?  (i.e., values in the new conf file are used)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve that:

1. You either set a classpath to include `application.conf` from external directory and appear on the classpath before other classpath entries like your jar. To do that you can use regular `java -classpath myconfdir:theapp.jar` and specify main class explicitly.
2. You can alternatively include another conf file into your file with `include "application"` directive in your conf file.
3. You can set environment variable in `application.conf` that will point to a file to include. You set env in shell afterwards.
4. You can override values programmatically: `config.withValue("hostname", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("localhost")`. `ActorSystem` takes a Conf object or loads from default conf if not provided.
5. **The easiest** by far is to just pick another file with `-Dconfig.resource=/dev.conf` java command line argument.

For more details refer to official docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html).

Comment: Thanks for that, Aleksey. Your response pointed me at `-Dconfig.file=...` which is what I was after.

Answer (score 5):

We do it in prod like so:

```
#deploy_prod.conf
include "application"

akka.remote.hostname = "prod.blah.com"    

# Example of passing in S3 keys
s3.awsAccessKeyId="YOUR_KEY"
s3.awsSecretAccessKey="YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
```

The above file must end in `.conf`. It has all the production environment specific configs, and lives **outside** the jar, so you deploy an identical Akka artifact to all servers. It will override anything in `application.conf`.

Then in the startup script:

```
java -Dconfig.file=/full/path/deploy_prod.conf -jar your.jar com.your.Main
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to programmatically override default akka config with:

```
val customConf =
      ConfigFactory.parseString(s"""
            akka {
              persistence.snapshot-store.local{
                dir = target/snapshot
              }
              persistence.journal.leveldb.dir = target/journal
            }
        """)
val config = customConf.withFallback(original).resolve()    
logger.info(config.root().render())
val system = ActorSystem("iSystem", config)
```