# Scala Config: Include another file.conf

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

Currently, I have a `resources/application.conf` file which has the following keys:

```
development {
    server = www.myapp.com
    aws_key = my_aws_key
    aws_secret = my_aws_secret

}
```

I would like to remove my `aws_key` and `aws_secret` from the file.

I was thinking of creating another file called `resources/credentials.conf` and storing my personal authentications there.

```
credentials {
    aws_key = my_aws_key
    aws_secret = my_aws_secret
}
```

and then `include` it some way in my `application.conf` or merge that config to the `Config` object in addition to `application.conf`.

`credentials.conf` would be git ignored. A sample file would be checked in `credentials-sample.conf` which each developer would change according to his own credentials and rename the sample file to `credentials.conf`

I tried different variation of `include` like

- include "credentials"
- include "credentials.conf"
- include "./credentials.conf"
- include file("./credentials.conf")

and so on.

I know I can pass it via system variables but I would like to try it like mentioned above. If you know of a better way, please let me know.

Comment: 'Include' is a good way to do it. Did it not work?

Comment: Take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966621/overriding-multiple-config-values-in-typesafe-config-when-using-an-uberjar-to-de.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov: It's my mistake. 'include' did work. I was doing a 'ConfigFactory.load().getConfig('development') which excluded the credentials.conf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typesafe Config provide the way to fallback from one configuration to another. You can try the ConfigFactory.Load() to load different config and use withFallback to line them up in your designated order. Such as:
`ConfigFactory.Load("credentials.conf") withFallback ConfigFactory.Load("application.conf")`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your conf file, add

```
include "another_file.conf"
```

ie: https://github.com/cicco94/scala-akka-slick-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.conf

Comment: This doesn't work if the config is in a child directory. IE. `include "child/another_file.conf"`. How to make this work?