# cant override Typesafe configuration on commmandline in spark

Tags: apache-spark, properties, classpath, typesafe-config

I have a typesafe configuration `application.conf` in the `src/main/resources`folder which is loaded by default.

A single value can be overridden by specifying:

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-DsomeValue="foo"
```

However, specifying a complete new, i.e. overriding `application.conf` file like:

```
spark-submit \
    --class my.Class \
    --master "local[2]" \
    --files foo.conf \
    --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath="-Dconfig.file=file:foo.conf" \
    --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dvalue="abcd" \
    job.jar
```

will fail to load `foo.conf`. Instead, the original file from the resources folder will be loaded.
Trying the tricks from: [Using typesafe config with Spark on Yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507436/using-typesafe-config-with-spark-on-yarn) did not help as well.

## edit

[Overriding multiple config values in Typesafe config when using an uberjar to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966621/overriding-multiple-config-values-in-typesafe-config-when-using-an-uberjar-to-de) seems to be the answer for plain (without spark) programs.
The question remains how to bring this to spark.

Also passing:

```
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath="-Dconfig.resource=file:foo.conf"
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath="-Dconfig.resource=foo.conf"
```

fails to load my configuration from the command line .

Though, according to the docs:

> https://github.com/lightbend/config For applications using
>   application.{conf,json,properties}, system properties can be used to
>   force a different config source (e.g. from command line
>   -Dconfig.file=path/to/config-file):
>
> - config.resource specifies a resource name - not a basename, i.e. application.conf not application
> - config.file specifies a filesystem path, again it should include the extension, not be a basename
> - config.url specifies a URL
>
> These system properties specify a replacement for
>   application.{conf,json,properties}, not an addition. They only affect
>   apps using the default ConfigFactory.load() configuration. In the
>   replacement config file, you can use include "application" to include
>   the original default config file; after the include statement you
>   could go on to override certain settings.

it should be possible with these parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
spark-submit \
    --class my.Class \
    --master "local[2]" \
    --files foo.conf \
    --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dvalue='abcd' -Dconfig.file=foo.conf" \
    target/scala-2.11/jar-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

changing from `spark.driver.extraClassPath`to `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` is doing the trick

Comment: Hello @Georg Heiler
Can you please advise me on this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094327/how-to-use-databricks-job-spark-configuration-spark-conf?noredirect=1#comment109830651_62094327