# How to use Databricks Job Spark Configuration spark_conf?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, typesafe

I have a sample Spark Code where I am trying to access the Values for tables from the Spark Configurations provided by spark_conf Option by using the typeSafe application.conf and Spark Conf in the Databricks UI.
The code I am using is below,

When I hit the Run Button in the Databricks UI, the job is finishing successfully, but the println function is printing dummyValue instead of ThisIsTableAOne,ThisIsTableBOne...

I can see from the Spark UI that, the Configurations for TableNames are being passed to the Spark job, but these values are not getting reflected in the Code.

```scala
    try {

    val inputConfig = AppConfig.getConfig("input")
    val outputConfig = AppConfig.getConfig("output")

    val tableA = inputConfig.getString("tableA")
    val tableB = inputConfig.getString("tableB")
    val tableC = outputConfig.getString("tableC")

    println(
    s"""
    |$tableA
    |$tableB
    |$tableC
    |""".stripMargin)

    val userDataInTable = sparkSession.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (1, "dummy", "dummy", "dummy")

    )).toDF("id", "col2", "col3", "col4")

    userDataInTable.show(false)

    println("Completed Entry ")


    } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
    sparkSession.stop()
    e.printStackTrace
    }
    //application.conf contains below text,

    spark.tableNameA="dummyValue"
    spark.tableNameB="dummyValue"
    spark.tableNameC="dummyValue"
    input{
    tableA=${spark.tableNameA}
    tableB=${spark.tableNameB}
    }
    output{
    tableC=${spark.tableNameC}
    }

    //AppConfig
    val appConfig = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
    def getConfig(moduleName: String): Config = {
    val config = appConfig.getConfig(moduleName)
    config
    }
```

Comment: What is that `AppConfig` that you have there? I would first see if it is actually loading the proper application.conf and how are you supplying the application.conf

Comment: @Saša Zejnilović
I've updated the Code Snippet in the question.

Comment: Your app doesn't see application.conf on a path provided. But typesafe config wont complain.

Comment: @SašaZejnilović I am trying to understand, So you are asking me to provide Path somewhere?

Comment: main/resources/application.conf
main/scala/com.dir1.dir2.dir3.util.AppConfig
are my Application Path Code piece location.

Comment: I tried below
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions "-Dconfig.file=application.conf"
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions "-Dconfig.file=application.conf"
But it didn't help :(

Comment: Can you create a fully reproducible example outside of databricks commited to github? Besides that 1) there are two possibilities A) use sparks config system B) typesafe. In case of A: you have to prefix all config parameters with spark - otherwise they are ignored. For B) make sure to have the properties set. Start simple A) set them on the CLI B) put in directly into the jar.

Comment: Hello, @GeorgHeiler Thank you for the Comment, As a workaround, I am just reading the configurations from a conf file in S3. But I'll definitely make that Reproducible code available. Looks like Databricks Spark Conf can only detect system defined spark.(options)=true and not user defined like spark.table=TableA ...